# What's my MySQL root password

Tags: linux, passwords, mysql

I just installed mysql-server with the following command

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

Then when I call the command `mysql_secure_installation` MySQL asks to enter the root password:

[image: uxm]

I haven't set a password for mysql-server and is asking me for it.

How can I set the proper password? Is there a default password?

Comment: I had not setup anything

Comment: Please post text, no a link to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It needs to be execute as `superuser`

I had to execute `$ sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Also if I want to log in the `mysql` on the terminal I must `sudo` it

Comment: [Check my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1377703/167207). There is no reason you need to run `mysql` commands via `sudo`.

Comment: @JakeGould actually.. recent installs (ubuntu, mint, maybe debian) have been using unix socket authentication.  If hte connection is made via socket (default for `mysql` client) then the *nix username is trusted and authentication is done automatically.  Drove me nuts first time I ran into it a few months ago, since hte typical "restart w/o privs and set a new password for root" steps all work w/o error or other indication.  there is another column that needs updating to use said set password vs. socket auth.

Comment: @ivanivan Good to know. Read up on it and it seems that is exactly the scenario the original poster was facing. Updated my answer to reflect this new info.

Answer (score 3):

While the original poster claims to have found a solution to this issue [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1377696/167207), it made no sense to me. But now I understand some Debian/Ubuntu distros use a socket-based authentication method. This method of authentication being enabled by default would naturally require one use `sudo` to get into MySQL as they describe.

But in general, there is no reason to run `mysql_secure_installation` via `sudo`. That makes no sense in most cases since MySQL doesn’t need `sudo` for a client transaction like this… Unless socket-based authentication is at play. And `mysql_secure_installation` is just a Bash script that runs a pile of commands in a nice, convenient package to allow updating of some MySQL related security items. Just look at [the source code](https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/scripts/mysql_secure_installation.sh) to see what I mean.

So if you are on a system that *doesn’t* use socket-based authentication and you are facing a similar issue, the solution is either the password is blank for older versions of MySQL. So you would just run this to get into MySQL:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Or in the case of `mysql_secure_installation`, just hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompted for a password.

Or for modern versions of MySQL—I believe MySQL 5.7 or higher—you need to check the error log for a message like this:

> “2016-05-16T07:09:49.796912Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 8)13ftQG5OYl”

This is an example taken from [the Persona blog entry on this topic](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/18/where-is-the-mysql-5-7-root-password/). As to where this MySQL log entry is, it could be in `/var/log/mysqld.log` on a CentOS/RedHat server or it shows up as output from the package install on Ubuntu/Debian systems.

But simply checking the error log for the text “temporary password” will provide you with the initial `root` password MySQL sets when it is first installed.

Comment: Which version of mysql you got?

Comment: @Hector What does the version of MySQL matter? Look at my edit to understand what I mean.

Comment: This is the message on the error,log file `2018-11-23T01:04:26.841276Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
`

Comment: Also I changed the password by doing the step 3 this Digital Ocean MySQL Install and Configuration https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04. But I had to `sudo` my way in on `mysql`. I restart the server, I checked the mysql login and I don't need to `sudo` my way in to MySQL from the terminal to the server.

Comment: @Hector When the error message states, `root@localhost is created with an empty password` then the first part of my answer where I state you can just enter a blank password holds true. Your install of MySQL was setup without a password. All you had to do to get into MySQL secured is to run `mysql_secure_installation` and when it asked for a password just hit “Enter” or “Return” and you are set.

Comment: Well I didn't know. I had setup local servers before on virtual box and this is the first time it happens. I did pressed `return` and nothing happended. I'll tried again in other server. For now, I can log. thanks.