# MySQL / phpMyAdmin can't login? mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I've recently reinstalled my KVM server because I couldn't install MySQL-server correctly.

Now I've chosen to install MySQL-server by factory-installation.

And the following problem occurred, I have tried to solve it by myself and googled and tried every method, but none worked.

Maybe you can help.

[image]

And in my first try to log in, there was a completely other text.

> "Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS"

…or something like that.

Comment: Did you use the newly set root password? If you installed MySQL 5.7 or newer, you should check what the temp password is on the server by running this command: `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`. And then after you get the temp password run this command to secure your MySQL installation which also means setting a new `root` password: `mysql_secure_installation`. More details can be [found here](https://superuser.com/a/1377703/167207).

Comment: i got this by entering the grep command : 
http://prntscr.com/rsz5hf

Comment: Interesting. Seems to me this is a MySQL root password. If you can login to MySQL via root, you should be able to solve this.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/rsz714
Got this

Comment: The error indicates that `root@localhost` is not authorized your server

Comment: i know... but how do i solve it?